# Set body to backwards with JS bookmarklet

Tags: bookmarklet

Is there a way to change the body of a website to backwards? I tried `javascript:document.body.innerHTML = '<bdo dir="rtl" >' + document.body.innerHTML + '</bdo>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the tags explicitly. For example:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var txtEls = window.document.body.querySelectorAll("p, a, td");
    for (i = 0; i < txtEls.length; i++) {
        txtEls[i].innerHTML = '<bdo dir="rtl">' + txtEls[i].innerHTML + '</bdo>';
    }
})();
```

Try to run the bookmarklet on this page.